# Google Guice & Jersey multiple URL patterns to same servlet while applying package filtering

Tags: java, url, jersey, jetty, guice

I am trying, using Jersey & Google Guice 3.0, to map 2 different URL patterns to the same servlet and each of these URL patterns to be applied to a different package in my project.

To be clear I am pasting part of the code below and I will also explain.

**web.xml**

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.abc.web.listeners.GuiceContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**GuiceContextListener**

```
public final class GuiceContextListener extends GuiceServletContextListener {
...
    private JerseyServletModule getJerseyServletModule() {
        JerseyServletModule jerseyModule = new JerseyServletModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configureServlets() {
                filter("/*").through(WebServerStateFilter.class);
                final Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append("com.abc.web.stats.services");
                params.put(PackagesResourceConfig.PROPERTY_PACKAGES, sb.toString());
                serve("/api/v1/*").with(GuiceContainer.class, params);

                final Map<String, String> params1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
                sb1.append("com.abc.web.stats.otherservices");
                params1.put(PackagesResourceConfig.PROPERTY_PACKAGES, sb1.toString());
                serve("/api/*").with(GuiceContainer.class, params1);
            }
        }
    }
...
}
```

So basically I want:

- URLs starting with **"/api/v1/*"** to be handled through servlet GuiceContainer by services in package "com.abc.web.stats.**services**"
- URLs starting with **"/api/*"** to be handled through same servlet GuiceContainer by services in package "com.abc.web.stats.**otherservices**"

I used the code above but it does not seem to work, it seems that only the first "serve" call is taken into consideration so in this case only URLs matching "/api/v1/*" are served. 
I do not want to hardcode "v1" in my services since the version might change (to "v2") in the future.

Can somebody help me out?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your current endpoints should be refactored, but anyway your code looks a bit more complicated than neccesary. In my case it works like this.

```
...
String packages = "com.abc.web.stats.services;com.abc.web.stats.otherservices";
params.put(PackagesResourceConfig.PROPERTY_PACKAGES, packages);

serve("/api/v1/*").with(GuiceContainer.class, params);
serve("/api/*").with(GuiceContainer.class, params);
...
```

Jersey can scan multiple packages with a list separated by ;

Maybe you should change your "api/*" endpoint but I'm not really sure about how Jersey will work in that situation. I could bet it works fine with this code.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. I think that by default, GuiceContainer specified in the serve function will be created as singleton, thus, even though you have different params for it, it will still be serve under the same path.

To get around the issue, I had to create a different GuiceContainer. However, creating GuiceContainer requires an Injector as parameter, which you might not have in configureServlets function. Thus a provider is used to inject the GuiceContainer when it is needed. Guice Key is used so we ensure a different instance of it is created.

```
public final class GuiceContextListener extends GuiceServletContextListener {
    private JerseyServletModule getJerseyServletModule() {
        JerseyServletModule jerseyModule = new JerseyServletModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configureServlets() {
                filter("/*").through(WebServerStateFilter.class);
                final Map<String, String> params1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append("com.abc.web.stats.services");
                params.put(PackagesResourceConfig.PROPERTY_PACKAGES, sb.toString());
                bind(GuiceContainer.class)
                  .annotatedWith(Names.named("path1"))
                  .toProvider(GuiceContainerProvider.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
                serve("/api/*").with(Key.get(GuiceContainer.class, Names.named("path1")), params1);

                final Map<String, String> params2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
                sb2.append("com.abc.web.stats.otherservices");
                params2.put(PackagesResourceConfig.PROPERTY_PACKAGES, sb2.toString());
                bind(GuiceContainer.class)
                  .annotatedWith(Names.named("path2"))
                  .toProvider(GuiceContainerProvider.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
                serve("/api/*").with(Key.get(GuiceContainer.class, Names.named("path2")), params2);
            }
        }
    }
    ...
    private GuiceContainerProvider implements Provider<GuiceContainer> {
        @Inject
        private Injector injector;
        @Override
        public GuiceContainer get() {
          return new GuiceContainer(this.injector);
        } 
    }
}
```

Not sure if this is best practice but it helped me get around the issue.